# Defining a two-way link

Tags: mysql

I have a `users` table, and I want to define a "friends" relationship between two arbitrary users.

Up until now, I've used two different methods for this:

1. The `friends` table contains `user1` and `user2`. Searching for users involves a query that looks like
   `` ... WHERE @userid IN (`user1`,`user2`) ``, which is not terribly efficient
2. The `friends` table contains `from` and `to` fields. Initiating a friend request creates a row in that direction, and if it accepted then a second row is inserted with the opposite direction. There is additionally a `status` column that indicates that this has happened, making the search something like:
   `` ... WHERE `user1`=@userid AND `status`=1 ``

I'm not particularly satisfied with either of these solutions. The first one feels messy with that `IN` usage, and the second seems bloated having two rows to define a single link.

So that's why I'm here. What would you suggest for such a link? Note that I don't need any more information saved with it, I just need two user IDs associated with each other, and preferably some kind of status like `ENUM('pending','accepted','blocked')`, but that's optional depending on what the best design for this is.

Comment: On the subject of enums: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Comment: Short of some MySQL idiosyncrasy, there is no reason why `... WHERE @userid IN (\`user1\`,\`user2\`)` should be inefficient, assuming there is an index on `{\`user1\`}` (or better yet, a covering composite index on `{\`user1\`, \`user2\`}`, or even a clustered index).

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: I can't think of any index that would be used by a query condition such as `@userid IN (\`user1\`,\`user2\`)` - an index on `{\`user1\`}` wouldn't cover `user2` at all, while an index on `{\`user1\`,\`user2\`}` would require a matching condition for `user1` before it could check `user2`.

Comment: @MarkBannister `@userid IN (\`user1\`,\`user2\`)` is equivalent to `@userid = \`user1\` OR @userid = \`user2\``, which would benefit from separate indexes that have `\`user1\`` and `\`user2\`` at the leading edge, so you are correct - I have only covered one "half" of the query and if I wanted to cover both I'd need composite indexes in both "directions". BTW, I used the term "covering" in a sense described [here](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are in general two approaches:

1. Store each friend pair once, storing the friend with the least id first.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE
           friend
           (
           l INT NOT NULL,
           g INT NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY
                   (l, g),
           KEY (g)
           )
   ```
2. Store each friend pair twice, both ways:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE
           (
           user INT NOT NULL,
           friend INT NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY
                   (user, friend)
           )
   ```

To store additional fields like friendship status, acceptance dates etc. you usually utilize a second table, for reasons I'll describe below.

To retrieve a list of friends for each user, you do:

```
SELECT  CASE @myuserid WHEN l THEN g ELSE l END
FROM    friend
WHERE   l = @myuserid 
        OR
        g = @myuserid
```

or

```
SELECT  g
FROM    friend
WHERE   l = @myuserid
UNION
SELECT  l
FROM    friend
WHERE   g = @myuserid
```

for the first solution; and

```
SELECT  friend
FROM    friend
WHERE   user = @friend
```

To check if two users are friends, you issue this:

```
SELECT  NULL
FROM    friend
WHERE   (l, g) =
        (
        CASE WHEN @user1 < @user2 THEN @user1 ELSE @user2 END,
        CASE WHEN @user1 > @user2 THEN @user1 ELSE @user2 END
        )
```

or

```
SELECT  NULL
FROM    friend
WHERE   (user, friend) = (@user1, @user2)
```

---

Storage-wise, the two solutions are almost the same. The first (least/greatest) solution stores twice as few rows, however, for it to work fast you should have a secondary index on `g`, which, in fact, has to store `g` plus the part of the table's primary key which is not in the secondary index (that is, `l`). Thus, each record is effectively store twice: once in the table itself, once again in the index on `g`.

Performance-wise, the solutions are almost the same too. The first one, though, requires two index seeks followed by index scans (for "all friends"), the second one just one index seek, so for the L/G solution I/O amount might be slighly more. This might be mitigated a little by the fact that the one single index may become one level deeper than two independent ones, so the initial search may take one page read more. This may slow down "are they friends" query a little for the "both pairs" solution, compared to L/G.

---

As for the additional table for extra data, you most probably want it because it's usually much less used than the two query I described above (and usually only for history purposes).

Its layout also depends on the kind of queries you are using. Say, if you want "show my last ten friendships", then you may want to store the timestamp in "both pairs" so that you don't have to do filesorts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
);

INSERT INTO `users` (`uid`, `username`) VALUES
(1, 'h2ooooooo'),
(2, 'water'),
(3, 'liquid'),
(4, 'wet');


CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid_from` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uid_to` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('pending','accepted','blocked') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid_from` (`uid_from`),
  KEY `uid_to` (`uid_to`)
);

INSERT INTO `friends` (`id`, `uid_from`, `uid_to`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 3, 'accepted'), -- h2ooooooo sent a friend request to liquid - accepted
(2, 1, 2, 'pending'), -- h2ooooooo sent a friend request to water - pending
(3, 4, 1, 'pending'), -- wet sent a friend request to h2ooooooo - pending
(4, 4, 2, 'pending'), -- wet sent a friend request to water - pending
(5, 3, 4, 'accepted'); -- liquid sent a friend request to wet - accepted
```

I'd use something like the following:

```
SELECT
    fu.username as `friend_username`,
    fu.uid as `friend_uid`
FROM
    `users` as `us`
LEFT JOIN
    `friends` as `fr`
ON
    (fr.uid_from = us.uid OR fr.uid_to = us.uid)
LEFT JOIN
    `users` as `fu`
ON
    (fu.uid = fr.uid_from OR fu.uid = fr.uid_to)
WHERE
    fu.uid != us.uid
AND
    fr.status = 'accepted'
AND
    us.username = 'liquid'
```

Result:

```
friend_username | friend_uid
----------------|-----------
h2ooooooo       | 1
wet             | 4
```

Here `us` would be the user you want to query for friends, and `fu` would be the users friends. You could easily change the `WHERE` statement to select the user in whatever whay you want. The status could be changed to pending (and should only join on `uid_to`) if you want to find friends request that the users hasn't answered.

[**DEMO ON SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ac59/1/0)

The `EXPLAIN` if we use `us.uid` to match the user (as it's indexed):

[image]

Comment: Aren't the two JOIN ON conditions identical? `a = b` implies `b = a`

Comment: @Kolink `us` will, as said, only contain the user you want to query. `fr` will contain the links (and the UID's) and `fu` (FriendUsers) will contain the friends user records. Hence they're not identical. If you only want UID's, you don't need the `fu` JOIN.

Comment: @Kolink It might seem complex-ish, but it works fine - supports indexes (take a look at the `EXPLAIN`) and is quick. It's certainly better than keeping two records (A is friends with B and B is friends with A).

Comment: I just tried running your query on my existing data (as described in option 1 in the question, which seems to be what you're suggesting). While it is about 40% faster than doing a single ``JOIN ON `users`.`id`=IF(`friend`.`from`=@userid,`friend`.`to`,`friend`.`from`)``, it fails to return all matching rows...

Comment: @Kolink Could you do us a favour and create an SQL Fiddle with the minimum schema in which it fails?

Comment: Your schema is practically identical to mine, just with different column names (which I updated before running the query)

Comment: @Kolink How many rows do you have? What's your relations? Could you post your tables in the OP, so I can check what goes wrong?

Comment: The `friends` table currently contains 423,208 rows. And as I said, the tables are identical, right down to the indexes you have defined.

Comment: @Kolink And there's no obvious reason as to why those specific rows are not displayed? They don't look any different?

Comment: I also can't see why this would fail to find matches. However with the OR conditions in the JOINs I don't think it is going to use indexes efficiently (ie, on the friends table it has a choice of an index on uid_from or uid_to, and it has to pick one index or the other). It possibly should use INNER JOINs rather than LEFT OUTER JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

Performance considerations aside, another option might be a "friend" table in which one row represents a friend (does not matter which way around), together with a view which produces two result rows (one in each direction) for any friend row. In use, it would simplify queries because it could be used in the same way as the "two row" solution while only requiring one data row per "friendship".

The only drawback could be performance... depending on how the query optimizer works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to be creative, here are some results.

Easier drawn than said,

---

[image: Diagram]

A simple trigger on table *friends* would do a nice service, ordering (user1,user2) without forgeting who requested friendship.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `friends_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON friends
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE X INT UNSIGNED;
  IF NEW.user1 > NEW.user2 THEN
    SET X = NEW.user1;
    SET NEW.user1 = NEW.user2;
    SET NEW.user2 = X;
    SET NEW.invited_by = 1;
  END IF;
END$$
```

---

Finally, let's say a user U has id = x. We can say U divides table *users* in two parts: users with id < x and ones with id > x. Before inserting a tuple into table *friends*, we order its ids, and so a certain information won't be explicitly written twice.
We obtain friends of our user U (id = x) through union of U's friends with id < x and ones with id > x:

```
SELECT user1 AS `friend_id` FROM friends
  WHERE user1<@id AND user2=@id
UNION
SELECT user2 AS `friend_id` FROM friends
  WHERE user2>@id AND user1=@id;
```

The main goal here is query performance. Dividing in these two cases would help MySQL to use the right index for each situation.
*[ Time for questions & disagreement. Perhaps you want the complete SQL; it's shown [here](http://pastie.org/8061913) ]*

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/219dae/3/0

Here is the code:

The SCHEMA:

```
-- This is the users table:
CREATE TABLE users
    (
     u_id int auto_increment, 
     username varchar(20),
     PRIMARY KEY (u_id) 
    );

INSERT INTO users (username)
VALUES ('user1'),
       ('user2'),
       ('user3'),
       ('user4'),
       ('user5');

-- This is the friends table:

CREATE TABLE friends
    (
     f_id int auto_increment,
     r_name varchar(20), -- the name of the user that requests for friendship
     a_name varchar(20), -- the name of the user that answers the friendship request
     status varchar(20), -- the status of the request
     PRIMARY KEY (f_id)
    );

-- below, user1 sends frind requests to user2, user3, user4 and user5; and receives one from user2:

INSERT INTO friends (r_name, a_name, status)
VALUES ('user1','user2', 'pending');

INSERT INTO friends (r_name, a_name, status)
VALUES ('user1','user3', 'pending');

INSERT INTO friends (r_name, a_name, status)
VALUES ('user1','user4', 'pending');

INSERT INTO friends (r_name, a_name, status)
VALUES ('user1','user5', 'pending');

INSERT INTO friends (r_name, a_name, status)
VALUES ('user2','user1', 'pending');

-- user1 accepts user2 request to be his friend:

UPDATE friends
SET status='accepted'
WHERE a_name='user1' AND r_name='user2';

-- user3 accepts user1 request to be his friend:

UPDATE friends
SET status='accepted'
WHERE a_name='user3' AND r_name='user1';
```

and the SELECT:

```
-- here we select all friend requests that the user1 received and all friend requests that he made

SELECT r_name, a_name, status FROM users
INNER JOIN friends ON users.username=friends.a_name
WHERE username='user1'

UNION

SELECT r_name, a_name, status FROM users
INNER JOIN friends ON users.username=friends.r_name
WHERE username='user1'
```